# How to customize the footer in joomla

Tags: templates, joomla, edit

I just started using joomla, so im a bit new to it. Im using version 4.1.0
I have added a footer on my site (Content - Site Modules - New - Footer)
The footer is where it is supposed to appear, but it seems that i cant edit it. I cant add icons and i cant edit the text that the Cassiopeia template has (
Copyright © 2022 joomlatutorial. All Rights Reserved.
Joomla! is Free Software released under the GNU General Public License.)
Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask your Joomla questions there.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is to create a Language Override for the footer.

The displayed text is determined by the native Language Strings of Joomla.
MOD_FOOTER_LINE1 and MOD_FOOTER_LINE2.

You will find a guide on how to do it here in section 4.4.3. Having a nice customized Footer: https://magazine.joomla.org/all-issues/february-2022/joomla-4-cassiopeia-template-a-bunch-of-tips-tricks

If you do not want to display any text for the second line, leave the text field blank when creating the language override.

Bonus tip:
You can use other module types than footer.
The Custom module allows you to write your own text/html using the WYSIWYG editor.

Best of luck! :)